# Is there a way to apply the synonym token filter in ElasticSearch to field names rather than the value?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, jsonschema, synonym, elasticsearch-plugin

Consider the following JSON file:

```
{
  "titleSony": "Matrix",
  "cast": [
    {
      "firstName": "Keanu",
      "lastName": "Reeves"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I know in ElasticSearch, you can apply a synonym token filter to field values as given in the following link: [Elasticsearch Analysis: Synonym token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).

Hence, I can create a "synonym.txt" file with `Matrix => Matx`, then if I search for `titleSony:Matx`, it will return the documents with `Matrix` as well.

Now, what I would like is to create a synonym for the field name `titleSony`. For example - `titleSony => titleAll`, such that when I search for `titleAll`, I should get all documents with `titleSony` as well.

Is there any way to accomplish this in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, what I would like is to create a synonym for the field name "titleSony". For example - titleSony => titleAll , hence when I search for "titleAll", I should get all documents with "titleSony" as well.

Yes, somewhat. Elasticsearch has some default behavior very similar to this, which I'll touch on in a bit.

The feature you're looking for is called "[Copy to field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#copy-to)." It allows you to specify that the terms in one field should be copied into another. This is useful for consolidating terms you expect to match into a single field, to help simplify your query when you would like to match against any one of a number of fields.

In this example, you would specify in your mapping that the terms in the `titleSony` field ought to be copied into the `titleAll` field. Presumably you'd have other fields (say, `titleDisney`) which also copy into that field as well. So a search against `titleAll` will effectively match the other fields whose terms are copied into it.

An excerpt of your mapping might look something like this:

```
{
  "movies" : {
    "properties" : {
      "titleSony" :   { "type" : "string", "copy_to" : "titleAll" },
      "titleDisney" : { "type" : "string", "copy_to" : "titleAll" },
      "titleAll" :    { "type" : "string" },
      "cast" : { ... },
      ...
    }
}
```

I mentioned earlier that Elasticsearch does something like this. By default it creates a special field called `_all` into which all the document's terms are copied. This field lets you construct very simple queries to match against terms that occur in any field on the document. So as you see, this is a fairly common convention in Elasticsearch. ([Elasticsearch mapping: _all field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html).)